# Ruby: How to replace text in a file?

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

The following code is a line in an xml file:

```
<appId>455360226</appId>
```

How can I replace the number between the 2 tags with another number using ruby?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no possibility to modify a file content in one step (at least none I know, when the file size would change).
You have to read the file and store the modified text in another file.

```
replace="100"
infile = "xmlfile_in"
outfile = "xmlfile_out"
File.open(outfile, 'w') do |out|
  out << File.open(infile).read.gsub(/<appId>\d+<\/appId>/, "<appId>#{replace}</appId>")
end
```

Or you read the file content to memory and afterwords you overwrite the file with the modified content:

```
replace="100"
filename = "xmlfile_in"
outdata = File.read(filename).gsub(/<appId>\d+<\/appId>/, "<appId>#{replace}</appId>")

File.open(filename, 'w') do |out|
  out << outdata
end
```

(Hope it works, the code is not tested)

Comment: Hey, so if the new data is shorter then the old data the end of the old data will still be in your file leaving you with a corrupt file.

Comment: @medmonds No. My solution rewrite the complete file. The problem you describe is why I wrote _at least none I know, when the file size would change_. If the file size changes, then the file would be corrupt. That's why there is no solution in one step.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
IO.write(filepath, File.open(filepath) {|f| f.read.gsub(//<appId>\d+<\/appId>/, "<appId>42</appId>"/)})
```

`IO.write` truncates the given file by default, so if you read the text first, perform the regex `String.gsub` and return the resulting string using `File.open` in block mode, it will replace the file's content in one fell swoop.

I like the way this reads, but it can be written in multiple lines too of course:

```
IO.write(filepath, File.open(filepath) do |f|
    f.read.gsub(//<appId>\d+<\/appId>/, "<appId>42</appId>"/)
  end
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
replace="100"
File.open("xmlfile").each do |line|
  if line[/<appId>/ ]
     line.sub!(/<appId>\d+<\/appId>/, "<appId>#{replace}</appId>")
  end
  puts line
end
```

Comment: This looks like it worked in irb but if I go and open the actual file it doesn't look like anything changed. Is this all the code to it? Or do I have to save something?

Comment: when you execute the script, use the redirection operator `>` to save to another file.

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to use an XML parsing tool, and example of which is [XmlSimple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/).

You did tag your question with regex.  If you really must do it with a regex then

```
s = "Blah blah <appId>455360226</appId> blah"
s.sub(/<appId>\d+<\/appId>/, "<appId>42</appId>")
```

is an illustration of the kind of thing you can do but [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by invoking sed in your shell, given that you are in the unix env:

`sed -i -E "s-<appId>[0-9]+</appId>-<appId>123</appId>-g" a.xml`

where `a.xml` is your filename